Containers and widgets sizes become smaller after calling setState in fluttler using screenUtil package
Layout that I have created

Broken layout after setState()

I am having a corner case while working with this package. So the problem is that when I call setState method on a stateful widget, the whole layout size just changes, the containers get smaller after rebuilding the tree, anyone knows how to encounter this problem with a proper solution?
I am using the screenutil package.
What I expected
dynamic layout per device screen size.
What happened
Layout crashes and resizes weirdly after calling setState.

Please show the code or we can only imaginate.

You will need to share the code for anyone to help you here.
